# how can I hide one of RGB channels in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried researching, but it seems like there are no solutions in ASP.NET, only webforms and such.

Can I hide RGB channels (say, only the RED channel) for a `.jpg`, for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"? Replace it with another color?

Comment: no, I mean like that to make it 0 (out of 255). for example : red= 0;

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\temp\\source.jpg"))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    {
        var c = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
        bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c.A, 0, c.G, c.B));
    }
    bmp.Save("C:\\temp\\target.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: If I try to run this thing, its getting an exception: "A generic error occurred in GDI+". on the "ImageFormat.Jpeg" thingy

Comment: @thormayer: I tested it using a console app and it works. It probably doesn't work for you cause of write permissions.

Comment: @thormayer yes, its most likely a permission thing. If you are running this from an ASP application the user account running the application pool must have rights to the directory.